# How to convert date from server to NSString in ios

Tags: php, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimeinterval

I get datetime from server in double and when I convert it to date string in ios, I get error of EXEC_BAD_ACCESS from the first line of code below.

For example,

date string from server: 1426923003

This is how I convert it:

```
     NSString *dateFromServer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,news.dateCreated];
    NSLog(@"date server: %@",dateFromServer);
    long long theDate = [dateFromServer longLongValue];

    NSTimeInterval interval=theDate;

    NSDate *datenew = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
    NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [_formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
    dateString=[_formatter stringFromDate:datenew];
```

I run this codes in method:
    `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}` in order to show date on each cell of tableview.

I don't know why it has error like this. How do we make work ? Thank you.

Comment: I will change it and check it now.

Comment: If you treat it as seconds since 1970 `2020270704` IS `Sat, 07 Jan 2034 18:18:24 GMT`. The [current unix timestamp is 1426926406](http://www.epochconverter.com).

Comment: what should I use beside since 1970 ?

Comment: You have to figure out what date format the server sends back to you.

Comment: it just gives me as string with this number

Comment: And you have to look at the documentation (or the code of the server) to see what this string actually means. Any chance that your conversion from string to number has failed?

Comment: ok, I will to ask server side about this.

Comment: so we cannot solve it if we don't know server code ?

Comment: I am wrong when I convert date from server , correct timestamp I recieve is 1426923003 that I can convert directly.

Comment: news.dateCreated is a string right?? What is the type of news

Comment: I create a class "News" that contains all properties and I initial it by using:         News *news = [ListOfNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: news.dateCreated is NSString.

Comment: I try to get date string like this:         NSString *dateFromServer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,news.dateCreated];

Comment: But I still get error of EXC_BAD_ACCESS in this line

Comment: I try to track it, and I see it stops at index 5 (    news = [ListOfNews objectAtIndex:5];
)

Comment: there are 13 data for all

Comment: Before index 5, date string is correct. For example : self->news->dateCreated:
1426856404

Comment: At index 5, it gives value: self->news->dateCreated:
<_UIFontExtraData: 0x791b2dd0>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date from server contains 13 digits..assign the date to long long instead of double

Comment: Did u try `long long`??

Comment: server side gives me all in json and this date as string, I don't know how they convert it

Comment: when I use long long, date number is 2022824320

Comment: and by my codes above, it gives result: 06-02-2034 02:38 PM

Comment: I am wrong when I convert date from server , correct timestamp I recieve is 1426923003 that I can convert directly.

Comment: When u get from server ul get nsstring 1426923003 right?

Comment: Then use longlongvalue method of nsstring to extract it to a long long.. Like this

Comment: Say the string is `serverdate = @"1426923003`… then do the following `long long theDate = [server longlongvalue];`

Comment: Say the string is `serverdate = @"1426923003`… then do the following `long long theDate = [serverdate longlongvalue];`

Comment: when I try it, I get signal SIGABRT. I use this code: long long theDate = [news.dateCreated longLongValue];
        
        NSTimeInterval interval=theDate;
        
        NSDate *datenew = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
        NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [_formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        [_formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
        [_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
        dateString=[_formatter stringFromDate:datenew];

Comment: Even I change like this: NSString *dateFromServer = news.dateCreated;
        NSLog(@"date server: %@",dateFromServer);
        long long theDate = [dateFromServer longLongValue];
        
        NSTimeInterval interval=theDate;

Comment: Which line do u get d exception

Comment: news.dateCreated is a string right?? What is the type of news

Comment: error this line: NSString *dateFromServer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,news.dateCreated];

Comment: news.dateCreated is NSString and type of news is NSOBject

Comment: After I assign double to server date and then long long , now it works without error. Thanks u